# How to open multiple windows one by one using a loop?

Tags: java, swing

I can open multiple windows using a loop.
Now I want to open these windows one by one. That means when I close one window the next window will be opened, I mean till the closing of a window the loop will be halted.

Here is the code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class WindowOpener {

    private static final int WINDOW_COUNT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_COUNT; i++) {
                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setSize(150, 250);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This shows 5 opened windows at a time.

Comment: Why? What is the point of doing something like this? The easiest solution is to use a modal JDialog. Then the looping code will wait until each dialog is closed.

Comment: In concurrence with the question of @camickr, this seems like an XY problem that is is better solved any number of different ways. 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to make a WindowListener.

```
WindowListener wl = new WindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent we) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent we) {
            //open new window
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setSize(150, 250);
            f.addWindowListener(this);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent we) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent we) {
        }
    };
```

In the WindowClosed part, you open a new window as you want, and make sure that you add the WindowListener to it.
Now, to start the process, you have to make a window, and add this listener to it. As soon as you closed that, it will make a new window.
You can limit the count of the opening windows with a variable outside the listener.

```
if(windowsLeft>0){
windowsLeft--;
//open window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. It shows one window at a time up to WINDOW_COUNT times and waits to open the next window until the previous one is closed.

```
private static final int WINDOW_COUNT = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createNewWindow(WINDOW_COUNT);
}


private static void createNewWindow(int count){

    if(count > 0) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        if(count == 1)
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit the program after last  window is closed
        else
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); //don't exit the program until last window is closed

        f.setSize(150, 250);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosed(e);
                createNewWindow(count -1); //call on window closed event.
            }
        });

    }
}
```